# Errors with setting up an Ionic app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I've just started to get my hands on the Ionic Framework to code my first Android app.

I can set up the project, but when I want to add the Android platform via 'ionic platform add' it says:

```
' ? Error reading config file: Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\Projects\android2\config.xml'
Error happened: undefined'
```

When I want to build the App via 'ionic build android' it says:
'Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.'

When I run the fix from the ionic FAQ ('cordova create') it says:

```
'At least the dir must be provided to create new project. See `cordova help`.'
```

Does anyone know why this errors happen?

Edit: tried on multiple computer (Windows 7 64), got the same error.

Comment: Can you post the content of config.xml please

Comment: You need to `cd android2` then do `ionic platform add android` . I find it better to `ionic hooks add` then do the `ionic platform add ...`

Comment: How did I not see, that it created another folder for the project ... maybe because it had the same name. Thank you, works fine now!

Answer (score 29):

Go inside the folder you will find another folder where you might be containing all the files related to your projects ,after going inside the folder write down the command  **'ionic platform add android'**...
For example:

**step1:** ionic start MyFirstApp blank

*after running this command a folder will be created in which to the drive where you run.*

**step2:** Go inside the folder name 'MyFirstApp' by running command 'cd MyFirstApp'

**step3:** Then write ionic platform add android

I think this will work for you! Happy Coding